# Override Keyclock JpaUserProvider

Tags: java, microservices, keycloak, licensing

Dose anybody know how overide Keyclock JpaUserProvider using extension?

Hi. It is required to call an external microservice to check the license when adding a user and roles to the keyclock. Can anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

To override the `JpaUserProvider` with extension, you need to create a custom `SPI` (Service Provider Interface). Use the `UserProvide`r interface to create a custom user provider and override the methods you think you might need.
Here's an example:

```
 public class CustomUserProvider implements UserProvider {
        
        private final EntityManager em;
        
        public CustomUserProvider(EntityManager em) {
            this.em = em;
        }

        @Override
        public UserModel addUser(RealmModel realm, String username) {
            UserModel user = ... // Add user to your database
            
            // Call your external microservice here
            
            return user;
        }
        
        // Override other methods...
    }

    public class CustomUserProviderFactory implements UserProviderFactory {

        @Override
        public UserProvider create(KeycloakSession session) {
            EntityManager em = session.getProvider(JpaConnectionProvider.class).getEntityManager();
            return new CustomUserProvider(em);
        }
        
        // Implement other methods...
    }
```

Note: You might want to look at [this article](https://medium.com/@bcarunmail/securing-rest-api-using-keycloak-and-spring-oauth2-6ddf3a1efcc2) for more info.

Comment: Oh, sorry, slightly misunderstood the question. Wanna to know how to change the current provider to your own?